# Multiply the Sum of one Cell if another cell shows value

Tags: excel, function, formula, worksheet

I'm trying to show multiple values in one cell based on the values in another on another sheet.

In the screenshot you'll see cell U78, I'd like that to either add or subtract an additional 10% based on the value of cell G23 in the Sales Agreement sheet. The formula I am trying is in the screen shot.

Here is where you'll see the formula I am trying to add 10%. I came up with the idea to put it on a different cell since I kept getting the "too many arguments" error and have it send the sum back to cell U78 where I need it.

Here is where you'll see the original formula in cell U78 subtracting 10%.
[image]

This is the drop down list I need the formula to be based on.
[image]

Comment: Excel's [IF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IF-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2) might be helpful here. It evaluates a condition. If the condition is true, the function returns the second parameter. Otherwise, it returns the third parameter. Example: IF(A7 < 1000; 0.1; 0.0)

Comment: ok so can I add IF('NextSheet!'A7="DaysOff",B7,0.1,"")? To show if true multiply by the sum of B7?

Comment: You have to use the correct syntax. IF has three parameters: the condition, the true-value and the false-value. Check the link in my comment.

Comment: Judging by that single formula available from your image you need a cross-reference table of discounts and surcharges associated with a number of line items and use [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65) to locate the correct amount.